# Is there a way to auto update or reproject newly added vertices on a shrinkwrapped mesh?

Tags: shrinkwrap

I am doing a retopology project where I am using a low poly mesh that is shrinkwrapped to the high poly reference mesh. I have **Snap during transform** enabled with the snap element set to Faces and **Project individual elements on the surface of other objects** enabled.

The trouble, as we know, is that when new points are added with the knife tool, the vertices don't automatically snap to the reference mesh until each and every newly added point is translated a tiny bit in order to get it to snap back on to the surface.

Is there an add-on or a trick to using Blender that will speed up this workflow or do I really have to manipulate every single added point to get it to snap to the surface after I add it?

PS - I figured out that if, after making the knife cut, I tap G then all the newly added verts seem to update. Did I find the only solution or is there something that will reproject newly added points automatically?

Comment: Surely that's the purpose of the Shrinkwrap - to continuously project vertices? You shouldn't need snapping on for that to work.

Comment: Now I am totally confused. I was sure I was having this problem with the Shrinkwrap Modifier before I tried using the Snapping feature...I need to go back and see what is up and why I am having problems if the Shrinkwrap Modifier is the solution I am looking for.

Comment: With snapping off, when I manipulate the mesh with just the Shrinkwrap Modifier, my components really get buried in the reference mesh. I am not sure why I am getting a different result.

Comment: Then I suggest adding screenshots and potentially uploading the file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks Ray, you helped me track it down as a simple workflow issue. I can now work without snapping on. I was missing the "Adjust edit cage to modifier result" on the Shrinkwrap Modifier. I will post the workflow as an answer and maybe it will help someone else who is having the same issue someday.

Comment: Even with the new workflow that I posted, I cannot get the points exactly where I want them without setting up Snapping AND the Shrinkwrap Modifier. I am convinced that they both need to be on, however I think "Project individual elements on the surface of other objects" actually needs to be off in this case.

Comment: I use the Shrinkwrap modifier all the time. By default the Shrinkwrap modifier only snaps to the surface, so if you want to snap a vertex in your low poly mesh to a vertex on your high-poly mesh, then yes, you will need snapping, otherwise you really shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q. What is the workflow to setup retopolgy with SubD in Blender?**

**A**.

1. Create your reference mesh:

   - In the *Properties Editor> Object tab> Display panel* set *Maximum Draw Type* to *Solid*.
2. Create your retopo mesh:

   - Create a plane as the beginning of your retopology mesh and name it.
3. Setup *X-Ray* for retopo mesh:

   - In the *Properties Editor> Object tab> Display panel* enable *X-Ray*.
4. Setup *Sudivision Surface Modifier* for the retopo mesh:

   - Add *Subsurface Modifier*.
   - Enable *Adjust edit cage to modifer result* icon.
   - Subdivisions level to 2 or whatever is desired.
5. Setup *Shrinkwrap Modifier* for retopo mesh:

   - Add *Shrinkwrap Modifier* with defaults.
   - Set the *Target* to the reference mesh.
   - Enable *Adjust edit cage to modifer result* icon.
6. Setup *Snapping to Faces* for retopo mesh:

   - In the *3D View* header, enable *Snap during transform* and set the
     *Snap Element* to *Face* but leave off *Project individual elements on the
     surface of other objects*.
7. Setup a viewport material for the retopo mesh:

   - In the *Properties Editor> Material tab*, add a new material.
   - Give it color like bright green or whatever you desire.
   - Copy the material color (hover over it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
   - Go to the *Material tab> Settings> Viewport Color*, hover over it and
     paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

**Update**: I discovered that if your shrinkwrapped mesh is misaligned in certain areas, a quick fix is to apply the shrinkwrap modifier and then add another shrinkwrap modifier and set it up again. All the misaligned points will be fixed without having to move them around individually in order to get them to update.

Comment: If someone can tell me how to indent a bullet point as a sub bullet point I will edit it the way I intended, in order for it to read better.

Comment: Seeing as this is a sequence of steps, instead of separate points, I suggest a numbered list instead. As for indenting, you can click [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help#advanced-lists).